# How to limit the number of concurrent processes using subprocess module in asyncio python

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
import asyncio.subprocess
args="blah blah argument "     
create=asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(args,stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
proc = await create
output= await proc.stdout.read( )
```

This is a part of my server code , which gets 1000s of parallel hits from clients.Now how should i limit the maximum number of subprocesses created by the server to run the argument blah blah . As this is code is using 100% of my cpu. I need to deploy other servers on smae cpu

Comment: Is it worth considering something like Celery and RabbitMQ? It might give you more scaleability and finer control in the long run. Just a thought.

Comment: The client connects through websocket. And the process i run is cpu bound .so i needed asynchronus support ,that made me to prefer asyncio . Does Celery and RMQ support this? I never used them :/

Comment: Celery is an asynchronous task queue, whereas RabbitMQ is the task broker. This article gives a nice example - http://suzannewang.com/celery-rabbitmq-tutorial/

Comment: It might not be suitable for your application, but worth exploring if you haven't come across it before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) is a way of limiting internal counter of simultaneous jobs:

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

async def do_job(args):
    async with sem:  # Don't run more than 10 simultaneous jobs below
        proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(args, stdout=PIPE)
        output = await proc.stdout.read()
        return output
```

Note, you should be sure count of jobs doesn't increase much faster then you can actually do them. Otherwise, you'll need something more complex than that.