# python Problems with using multiple processes to process files

Tags: python

The previous problem was solved:
[How do I control the number of child processes used to call external commands in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645531/how-do-i-control-the-number-of-child-processes-used-to-call-external-commands-in?noredirect=1#comment130052994_73645531)

the new question is how can i batch luanch cmd?the sample code can normal operation,But only the last file executes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1G5o.png)

```
def run(v):
    for i in os.listdir(output_lineEdit):  #use "for" list all files
        if i.split(".")[1] == "ma":  # use "if" choose ".ma" files
            mapath = i
            cmd = '"{mayaBatchPath}" -batch -file "{maPath}" -script "{melFile}" "{plugins}"'.format(
                    mayaBatchPath=MAYABATCHPATH,# mayabatch.exe path
                    melFile=melFile, #.mel files
                    maPath=output_lineEdit+"\\"+mapath, # maya source files
                    plugins="-noAutoloadPlugins",
            )
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)


def main():
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.map(run, range(10))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please create a [example]. Currently, the imports are missing and the example is much more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I solved the problem

Comment: Just read that before asking your next question :).

Comment: Okay, got it,thank you for your notice,I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include `subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)` in the loop. Thus `cmd` field only the last iteration is written and you use it

Comment: how can i write include subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True) in the loop

Comment: write 4 spaces before subprocess.run()

Comment: Thank you very much.I shouldn't have made such a stupid mistake